# How to integrate Transaction API in Action on Google

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Trying to integrate Transactions API for reservations only (No Payments required). While invoking transaction decision, the app is not responding and I hear “ is not responding right now. Try again soon.”

Here are my steps:

1. Check if transaction is required using transaction check 

2. Create order, cart and transaction config.  
3. Invoke transaction decision
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code, I want to keep my order with minimal information:

```
const order = assistant.buildOrder(`${new Date().getTime()}`)
    .setCart(assistant.buildCart().setMerchant('My Appointment', 'Appointment Project'));

const transactionConfig = {
    deliveryAddressRequired: false,
    type: assistant.Transactions.PaymentType.UNSPECIFIED,
    displayName: 'Book my appointment'
};

assistant.askForTransactionDecision(order, transactionConfig); // FAILS HERE
```

** assistant is app for dialogflow object

I have used the sample order from the [GIT repo](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/dev-guide#propose_the_order_to_the_user) as well with Sandbox mode enabled and disabled, but it is still not working.

Testing on Nexus 5, Android Marshmallow, Fake Location of US and Dialogflow NodeJS client

Comment: Did you take a look at the README (https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs/blob/master/README.md)? There are some troubleshooting and extra steps in there that you may need

Comment: Thanks, Sachit. One of your friends helped me last night :) Its resolved now. I have to use GPS mocking app for fake location and a US address account to access it. Also, my order was not correct in format.